# Angular RX get zip file and unzip it

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-nativescript

I am getting a zip file from backend and I need to unzip it's contents (bunch of json files for big offline data).

Api call:

```js
getOfflineTimetables() {
    let req = new Request(myOptions);
    return this.http.request(req)
        .map(res => {
            return res;
        })
}
```

When I was getting regular jsons, I just mapped it res.json()

For the zip I don't know how to map it, without mapping it doesn't work.

In my other service I am subscribing to getOfflineTimetables, but I don't how to pass the zip to my unzip(file) method. I am trying to write the file to file system and then unzip it.

```js
this.api.getOfflineTimetables().subscribe(res => {
    this.writeFile(res).then(written => {
        this.unzip(written);
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't get to the zip file from the Api call.

Comment: what is `writeFile` method expecting as parameter ? what  type ?

Comment: It's my method, which creates a file on filesystem and writes whatever is passed to it. Let's say string to make it easy, the problem is nothing gets passed in with zip.

Comment: the fact is you don't want to write a `Response` object to your disk, so you need to get the response body as binary data so `this.http.request(req).map(res => res.blob())` or `res.arrayBuffer()` depending on your needs. Please, don't try to "make it easy" because writing a zip file as string makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I can't map it to either of those. The idea of writing it to file system comes from the unzip plugin, ofc I'd streamline it it when done. But I can't get the reference to the zip itself. https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-zip

Comment: **You cannot write a `Response` object to the file system,** You need to write the file that it contains. Period.

Comment: But how do I get reference to the file?

Answer (score 0):

`Http` service returns an `Observable<Response>`, and you cannot write a `Response` to the filesystem, you need to write the file that it contains.

You can use the `.blob()` or `.arrayBuffer()` method of the `Response` object, depending on what accepts the `writeFile` method :

```
getOfflineTimetables():Observable<Blob> {
    let req = new Request(myOptions);
    return this.http.request(req)
        .map(res => res.blob())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I guess I should have specified my issue better. When I map to .blob() or .arrayBuffer(), it doesn't go to the subscribe. Is there some other way I can get the file out of the response object?

Comment: nope, please add the following informations to your question : Every headers of the response, is there actually a body ? if nothing happens that might be because the response is not a binary, what is the `Content-Type` Header of the response ?